# Add a new sound from files

Tags: matlab

I understand that the matlab have updated the wavread to audioread!I have my code using wavread how to convert to read file help please thanks.

if chos==1,

```
    clc;

    [namefile,pathname]=uigetfile('*.wav;*.au','Select a new sound');

    if namefile~=0

        pos = strfind(namefile,'.');

        ext = namefile(pos+1:end);

        if strcmp(ext,'au')

            [y,Fs,bits] = audioread(strcat(pathname,namefile));

        end
        if strcmp(ext,'wav')

            [y,Fs,bits] = wavread(strcat(pathname,namefile));

        end
```

the error giving is 
Undefined function or variable 'wavread'
[y,Fs,bits] = wavread(strcat(pathname,namefile));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `wavread` by `audioread`.
2. Replace `[y,Fs,bits]` by `[y,Fs]`.
3. If you still need the bits per sample information, infer it from the data type of `y`. Or just hardcode it.

Refer to https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html for more information on using the `audioread` function.